# how to send on contact form using phpmailer

Tags: php, email

```
      <html> 
      <form method="post" action="email.php">
   Email: <input name="email name" id="email" type="text" /><br/>
      Message:<br/><text area name="message" id="message" rows="15" cols="40</text area><br>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
       </form>
     <html/>
```

i have those code and i want to send email to myemail@gmail.com on a contact form but it says enter at least one recipient and when am entering email to $mail-> add address($email) if i change to $mail->addadress(someone@gmail.com) even if the email on a form is differ from default it will send to someone@gmail.com please help me.

```
<?php
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

require("PHPMailerAutoload.php");
require "class.phpmailer.php";

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
$mail->Port       = 587;   

$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  
$mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "*************"; // SMTP password
$mail->AddAddress=$email;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "You have received feedback from your website!";
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $message;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

Comment: `addAddress` is a function within the PHPMailer class so you need to pass the desired email as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

AddAddress is a method, not a property.

```
$mail->AddAddress=$email;
```

Should be:

```
$mail->AddAddress($email);
```

Comment: thankyou for your comment but still add atleast one receipent

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/441.  Check the output of `var_dump(PHPMailer::validateAddress($email));` to rule out the bug.  Which version of PHP?